Universality of Drag Coefficient Rate of Change with Reynolds Number for Arbitrary Bluff Body Geometries?
In our recent work, A Generalized Model for Predicting the Drag Coefficient of Arbitrary Bluff-Shaped Bodies at High Reynolds Numbers, we found that the rate at which the drag coefficient changes with the Reynolds number follows a universal pattern, no matter the shape of the bluff body considered or if it is two-dimensional or three-dimensional. This pattern holds from the laminar flow regime to the subcritical regime.
What’s particularly interesting (and hard to explain) is that this universality persists even in the laminar flow regime, where both friction and pressure forces are still at play. We have used this universal property to predict the drag coefficient in the subcritical flow regime just from knowing a single value of the drag coefficient at low Reynolds numbers. My question can we find a physical explanation for the phenomenon that we observe?
